# golang mysql DESCRIBE table causes driver.Value type nil error

Tags: mysql, go

I'm taking my first crack at using golang to query a MySQL database but I get the following error when I run the command `go run main.go`.

> 2017/10/22 21:06:58 sql: Scan error on column index 4: unsupported
>   Scan, storing driver.Value type  into type *string exit status 1

Here's my main.go

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "database/sql"
)

import _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"

var db *sql.DB
var err error

// main function to boot up everything
func main() {

    var dbField,dbType,dbNull,dbKey,dbDefault,dbExtra string

    // Create an sql.DB and check for errors
    db, err = sql.Open("mysql", "username:password@/mydatabase")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    rows, err := db.Query("DESCRIBE t_user")
    if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    for rows.Next() {
      err := rows.Scan(&dbField,&dbType,&dbNull,&dbKey,&dbDefault,&dbExtra)
      if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
      }
      log.Println(dbField,dbType,dbNull,dbKey,dbDefault,dbExtra)
    }
    err = rows.Err()
    if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // sql.DB should be long lived "defer" closes it once this function ends
    defer db.Close()

}
```

When I run the `DESCRIBE t_user` from mysql terminal, I get these results:

```
+------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                  | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| user_id                | int(11) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| first_name             | varchar(50)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| middle_name            | varchar(50)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name              | varchar(50)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email                  | varchar(50)         | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I can't seem to figure out what's causing the issue.  Is it because the columns key, default, extra sometimes returns empty string or null values?  I tried to do something like `var dbNull nil` but the compiler says `nil` is not a type, so if the issue is related to `dbNull` needing to accept nullable values, how does golang address this situation?  If that isn't the problem, I appreciate any other insight

Comment: I tried the above code as of Nov 19, 2018. It works well. I suspect that the problem reported was due to a bug in an old version.

Answer (score 0):

Index 4 is the `Default` column, which is nullable. You are giving it the address to place a string, but it needs to place NULL. The solution would be to use something like `sql.NullString` instead of just a string.

Answer (score 0):

As `Gavin` mentioned,

you need to use a type that handles null values such as [`sql.NullString`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullString).

As an alternative you can also have a new type that implements the [`db.Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Scanner) interface that handles nulls.

```
type dbNullString string

func (v *dbNullString) Scan(value interface{}) error {

    if value == nil {
        *v = ""
        return nil
    }

    if str, ok := value.(string); ok {
        *v = dbNullString(str)
        return nil
    }

    return errors.New("failed to scan dbNullString")
}
```

Also note that you need to implement the [`driver.Valuer`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/driver/#Valuer) interface to insert values using this type.